# Browser crashes for specific data in google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```js
var timeType = "year", data = JSON.parse('{"cols":[{"label":"Year","type":"string"},{"label":"Scans successful","type":"number"},{"label":"Scans failed","type":"number"},{"label":"Scans declined","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":0,"f":2016},{"v":5},{"v":0},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":1,"f":2015},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":2,"f":2014},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":3,"f":2013},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":4,"f":2012},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":5,"f":2011},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]}]}');
    
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chartReady);

function chartReady() {
  chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
  chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('comboMonthScan'));
  chart.draw(chartData, {
    seriesType: 'bars',
    chartArea: {
      'width': '90%',
      'height': '80%'
    },
    legend: {
      'position': 'top'
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="comboMonthScan" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

**WARNING: Running the code snippet may crash your browser!**

The data is valid according to the console.log output. For different numbers it works and shows the expected result, while showing this subset immediately freezes the UI, spikes the CPU to over 50% and starts consuming RAM until its forcably closed. I already [created a GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2361) but it looks like the repository is not maintained by Google.

Why does the problem exist, and how can i make it work? Do i use a keyword that crashes the visualization api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself: The other values were valid because as text-label (f) i used a string. I wanted to fill in the year and it got casted as number. This appears to crash the browser as Google Charts is unable to treat this number as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your followup.  The problem is an infinite loop when a number is provided instead of a string.  This problem will be avoided in the next release.